# How can I change the volume of a specific program?

Tags: gnome, sound, alsa

I just installed `gnome-alsa`, because my mic didn't work with `pulseaudio`. But I can't seem to find a way to change the volume of a specific program, like you can in Windows. I can only change the master volume. BTW, I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 64bit.

Answer (score 4):

Use [pavucontrol](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol) [image: Install pavucontrol]. It allows you to adjust volume of specific applications.

[image: pulse]

Comment: My problem is just that the sound my headset works with Pulseaudio but not the mic. Do you know if there's a way to do it with Alsa?